# Generic fact and dimension table in OLAP

Tags: generics, data-warehouse, olap, fact

I am designing a Datawarehouse. Is it possible to design a generic fact and dimension table.

I know this question may sound weird, but just wanted to know if there is anything as such, so that irrespective of the OLTP schema tables that I get I load it into the generic fact and dimension table.

Answer (score 1):

You would need the attributes that the users want to see as columns of your dimension tables, and the facts that they want to analyze in the fact table, hence these tables cannot be generic, but must be specific for the OLAP solution that you need.

There could be a generic solution for a date dimension, but even this will differ depending on the solution. It would at least depend on the granularity of the data. E. g. weekday does not make any sense if you have monthly granularity of data. But within the same granularity, to some extent, a date dimension could be generic.

Similarly, there could be partly generic geography, customer, or product dimensions. But these would also depend on granularity, requirements of data to be analyzed, and data available.

So the answer is for a certain domain like "retail product sales by day and geography", there could be generic solutions, but not one generic solution for OLAP. And even if you have a generic solution, possibly some adaptation will be necessary due to user requests and/or data availability.